# How to include calls to an $O(n)$ subroutine on finite-sized inputs in an analysis?

Tags: terminology, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

I am trying to calculate the runtime complexity of a function that does not have fixed size input, but uses several helper methods that do have fixed size input. I was unsure of how to include the helper methods in my calculations.

If I have an array with a fixed size of 32 indices, and I have a function that sums up the elements in that array, will that function be $O(n)$, or $O(1)$?  I think that a function that sums up the elements of an array is $O(n)$ because each element of an $n$-length array must be visited, but if the function only sums up arrays of length 32, is it still $O(n)$?

Comment: honestly it's useless to talk about Big O notation when using fixed size input

Comment: @ratchetfreak Note the updated question (based on a comment of fvrghi I have removed now); I think the question makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some things to consider here.

*Conceptually*, an algorithm that iterates once over the input array has runtime $\Omega(n)$ (and $O(n)$ if it does constant-time work per element), $n$ being the size of the array.

*In application*, if the algorithm is only ever called with arrays of length $n \leq n_0$ for some *constant* $n_0$, you may treat the used time as $O(n) \subseteq O(n_0) = O(1)$. Note that the $n$ here is probably not the one you use for your whole algorithm!

*In practice*, every algorithm runs constant time as real computers have finite memory. This is not an interesting model in the sense that it does not help to differentiate between algorithms that *do* behave very differently in practice, so we don't use it.

You may be interested in some of our reference questions on [asymptotics](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57/how-does-one-know-which-notation-of-time-complexity-analysis-to-use), [runtime analysis](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/192/how-to-come-up-with-the-runtime-of-algorithms) and the [time used by arithmetic operations](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1643/how-can-we-assume-that-basic-operations-on-numbers-take-constant-time).

Comment: Finite memory -> constant time? You can let an algorithm run for years. Shouldn't that be constant space?

Comment: @Dukeling: Well, *inputs* are finitely bounded in size, hence there are only finitely many of them and thus [expected] runtimes (for [in expectation] always terminating algorithms) are bounded by a constant, namely the maximum runtime that can be observed.

Comment: If memory is finite, the number of states of the computation is finite, something like $2^n$ where $n$ is the number of bits you can store (including registers, program counters etc). Either the program stops after $\le 2^n$ steps, or it never stops (once a state appears twice, the program loops).

Answer (score 2):

Any constant amount of work is O(1), whether it is summing up 32 values or brute forcing a 256 bit AES key.