# Can the runtime of functions with no loops change with the number of calls?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, runtime-analysis

How can we perform time complexity analysis on a function that has no loops?

```
int somefunction(int param) {
  if (something)
    do this;
  else
    do this;
}
```

Would the time complexity of this function change depending on how many times the function is called within a program? I currently believe that the time complexity is O(n), because it is dependent on the amount of times that we call it.

Comment: But what are "something" and "do this"? Do they need constant time only?

Comment: Have a look at our [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis) and see whether you can figure it out yourself. Hint: what about function calls and recursion?

Comment: @DavidRicherby: That would be a for-loop, contrary to what was asked. My interpretation was that there are no loops used directly of indirectly (thru method calls). (I also assumed in my answer that there are no recursive calls, since those are more-or-less equivalent to loops. The "no recursive calls" was not stated in the question, though.)

Comment: @rgrig Remind me to switch my brain on before I make any more suggestions! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The complexity is typically understood to be for one call. If you want to talk about the complexity of a sequence of calls, then you would need to say so.

In your example, you don't really gain anything by looking at sequences of calls. But there are other situations (with loops or recursive calls allowed) in which you would indeed want to look at sequences of calls. One example is when the function typically takes little time but once in a while it decides to do a lot of work. In that case, you need to quantify how ‘once in a while’ compares to ‘a lot of work’. A natural way to do so is to see how much it takes to execute a long sequence of calls (keywords: "amortized analysis").

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what `something` and `do this` are. In particular, do we have to assume global (or object) state?

Consider this:

```
int switch(int param) {
  if ( !set.contains(param) )
    set.add(param);
  else
    set.remove(param);
}
```

Now the runtime clearly depends on the implementation of `set` *and* the number of entries it has when `switch` is called. Calling `switch` $n$ times starting with an empty set and using pairwise distinct parameters, you might get $\omega(n)$ runtime in total, hence not all calls run in time $O(1)$.

On the other hand, if `somefunction` does *not* access state outside of its scope -- assuming that the function itself does not have persistent state -- the runtime can only depend on `param`. That does not mean runtime is in $O(1)$ -- `something` and `do this` may still do non-constant things. Call methods, recurse, etc.

Note that [depending on the cost model you use](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1643/98), even adding two numbers has non-constant cost.

Answer (score -1):

It does not become linear just because it is called by linear-worst-case code; it retains whatever complexity it would have in isolation, which here looks an awful lot like constant-time, barring certain odd edge cases. Big-O of a chunk of code is not evaluated based on code that might include it in its own Big-O; you don't consider a hashtable access linear just because there's code that uses the hashtable to process a whole list of items and increment their occurrence counts.

Comment: Not necessarily, it depends on what "something" and "do this" actually are.

Comment: @Juho: It seems you have (poorly) copied a catchphrase from a different answer without really explaining why the catchphrase is relevant or a rebuttal.

Comment: If you look at the time stamp of my comment to the original question, and the time stamp of the answer you are referring to, you will see this is not the case. To actually answer your question, it is clear that for instance, if `something` can't be performed in $O(1)$ time, the total time won't be $O(1)$ either. The same holds for `do this`.

Comment: @Juho : $\:$ How will he see that? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @Juho: Thanks anyway, but I already amended my answer. And no, expecting someone to look for a comment on the *question* that was the same as on the *answer* that drew the notification is … not particularly going to work.

Comment: @RickyDemer As far as I know a comment I make is seen by everyone, as is the time it was posted.

Comment: @Juho: Sure, I get that, and I leave comments much like that all the time myself. Just that this one wasn't helpful except, as it were, by accident.

Comment: @RickyDemer By looking at the comment and the timestamp printed next to it. The timestamp can be somewhat vague (e.g., "yesterday", "two months ago") but the mouse-over text always gives the exact time.