# Running time for threshold function evaluation?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, arithmetic

A threshold function is a function $f: \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}$, defined by $n$ integer-valued weights $w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_n$ and an integer valued threshold value $w_0$. It works as follows:
$$f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) = \begin{cases}0 \text{ if } \sum_{i=1}^n w_ix_i \ge w_0 \\ 1 \text{ otherwise.} \end{cases}$$.

I'm confused about the running time of evaluating $f(x)$ for some input $x \in \{0,1\}^n$. If we evaluate the running time as a function of $n$ (the number of bits that $f$ receives), then will this depend on the number of bits needed to represent $w_0, w_1, \ldots, w_n$?

Comment: It depends on your model of computation. It is common to assume you can do multiplication and addition in constant time so the running time would be $O(n)$ but if the numbers $w_i$ are very large this is not realistic. In that case, the running time would depend on the number of bits in the representation.

Comment: It's also known that every threshold function is equivalent to one in which all coefficients have bit-length $O(n\log n)$; so the weights don't have to be too ridiculous.

Comment: Duplicate of [this one](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1643/how-can-we-assume-that-basic-operations-on-numbers-take-constant-time)? Community votes, please!

Comment: Bringomial, you can *always* comment on your own posts, provided you use the same login.