# Time complexity of recursive power code

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, recursion

While I was learning about time complexity of recursive functions, I came across this code to calculate $x^n$:

```
power (x, n) {  
    if n == 0
        return 1 
    if n is even
        return power(x, n/2) * power(x, n/2)  
    if n is odd    
        return power(x, n/2) * power(x, n/2) * x
```

According to the book, its complexity is $\Theta(n)$ which seems rather strange to me. In my eyes, this code should have complexity $\Theta( n^2)$.

What am I seeing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think that it's $\theta(n^2)$? Can you show your analysis?

Comment: What is power macht(x,n/2) ?

Comment: @gnasher729. Presumably an artifact of translating the German original into English (since one translation of "macht" is "power").

Comment: It is crucial to fix the machine model; see also [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1643/how-can-we-assume-that-basic-operations-on-numbers-take-constant-time).

Answer (score 2):

### An Answer

I will take your code at face value under the [Uniform Cost Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Cost_models).

Let's now assume $n$ is of the form $n = 2^k$ where $k \in \mathbb{N} \wedge k \geq 0$ (e.g. $n$ is a power of $2$).

We then get a recurrence relation like so:

$$\begin{align}
T(x, n) & = 2 \cdot T\left(x,  \frac{n}{2} \right) + c \\[0.5em]
& = 4 \cdot  T\left(x,  \frac{n}{4} \right) + 2c + c \\
& = \vdots \\[0.5em]
& = \sum_{i = 1}^{\log_2 n} 2^{i - 1} \cdot c\\[0.5em]
& = c(n - 1)\\
& = \Theta(n)
  \end{align}$$

---

### Some Fun

Now let's take a step back and check out the [Logarithmic Cost Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Cost_models). Let's define the cost of multiplication as $g(n)$ where $n = \log_2 x$ (the size of $x$ in binary) and $x$ maximum of the two arguments.

Along with our prior assumption about $n$, let's also assume $x$ is of the form $x = 2^k$ where $k \in \mathbb{N} \wedge k \geq 0$ (e.g. $x$ is a power of $2$).

We get a recurrence of the form:

$$\begin{align}
T(n) & = 2 \cdot T\left(\frac{n}{2} \right) + g\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) \\[0.5em]
& = 4 \cdot  T\left(\frac{n}{4} \right) + 2 \cdot g\left(\frac{n}{4}\right) + g\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) \\
& = \vdots \\[0.5em]
& = \sum_{i = 1}^{\log_2 n} 2^{i - 1} \cdot g\left(\frac{n}{2^i}\right)\\[0.5em]
\end{align}$$

Now we can analyze some interesting multiplication methods:

1. Multiplication is [linear in size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Lower_bounds), e.g. $g(n) = n$.

$$
\begin{align}
T(n) & = \Theta(n \log n)
\end{align}$$

2. Multiplication is [quadratic in size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Usage_in_computers), e.g. $g(n) = n^2$.

$$\begin{align}
T(n) & = \Theta(n^2)
\end{align}$$

3. [Karatsuba Multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm#Efficiency_analysis), the divide and conquer method, e.g. $g(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_2 3})$

$$\begin{align}
T(n) & = \Theta(n^{\log_2 3})
\end{align}$$

4. Just for fun, and to plug Yuval's answer to my own question, multiplication is [super-linear-polylogarithmic and sub-polynomial-polylogarithmic](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/74627/68251), e.g. $g(n) = \Theta(n\log n \cdot 2^{\sqrt{2\log n}})$. We also assume size $n$ for $g$ instead of $\frac{n}{2}$.

   $$\begin{align}
   T(n) & = 2 \cdot T\left(\frac{n}{2} \right) + \Theta\left(n\log n \cdot 2^{\sqrt{2\log n}}\right) \\[0.5em]
   \end{align}$$

   We use case 3 of the Master Theorem to get:

   $$\begin{align}
   T(n) & = \Theta\left(n\log n \cdot 2^{\sqrt{2\log n}}\right) \\[0.5em]
   \end{align}$$

Essentially, but not exactly, as the time complexity becomes superlinear, the time it takes to multiply overtakes the recursive time. This can be seen as case 3 of the Master Theorem.

---

### Even More Fun!

Now let's say this was implemented in a smart manner, not repeating the recursive calls or using DP.

We get a recurrence of the form:

$$\begin{align}
T(n) & = T\left(\frac{n}{2} \right) + g\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) \\[0.5em]
& = T\left(\frac{n}{4} \right) + g\left(\frac{n}{4}\right) + g\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) \\
& = \vdots \\[0.5em]
& = \sum_{i = 1}^{\log_2 n} g\left(\frac{n}{2^i}\right)\\[0.5em]
\end{align}$$

The major improvement now is when multiplication is [linear in size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Lower_bounds), we now get linear exponentiation!

$$
\begin{align}
T(n) & = \Theta(n)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

The code as written is awfully bad: If n > 0 then it makes two recursive calls calculating the exact same result, which would make it θ(n). That's awfully bad because it can easily be done in  θ(log n) by making *one* call and multiplying the result by itself.

There is no reason to think this would be $θ(n^2)$. If it was $θ(n^2)$, that would be quite bad because even a simple dumb multiplication loop would run in θ(n).

Comment: Can you elaborate on the two vs one call issue? Wouldn't it be equivalent to say that this computation has a corresponding reccurence relation of $T(n)=2T(\dfrac{n}{2}) + \Theta (1)$ which boils down to $\Theta (n)$ by master theorem and/or checking the recursion tree?

Comment: @Sorrop The point is that it it's possible to modify this algorithm so that it uses only one recursive call to the half-size problem, which yields a timing function defined by $T(n) = T(n/2)+\Theta(1)$ under some assumptions, giving you $T(n)=\Theta(\log n)$.