# Useful functions between polylogarithmic and polynomial?

Tags: asymptotics

I'm wondering if there are any *useful* functions asymptotically greater than a polylogarithmic function and less than a polynomial function.

That is, a function $f(n)$ such that

$f(n) = \omega(\log(n)^k)$  for some constant $k > 0$

and

$f(n) = o(n^k)$ for some constant $k > 0$

What I mean by useful, is that it was used in a proof, algorithm, etc. rather than simply producing a function to fit these restrictions.

Answer (score 7):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom%E2%80%93Cook_multiplication) (which attributes the following result to Knuth), the running time of the mixed-level Toom–Cook algorithm for integer multiplication is
$$ \Theta(n\log n \cdot 2^{\sqrt{2\log n}}). $$
The function $2^{\sqrt{2\log n}}$ is super-polylogarithmic but sub-polynomial.