# Master theorem recurrence relation

Tags: asymptotics, master-theorem

Consider I have the following recurrence

$$T(n) = 10T(n/3) + \Theta(n^2\log^5 n)\,.$$

Now, by the master theorem, if we evaluate $n^{\log_{b}{a}}$, we get $n^{\log_{b}{a}} = n^{\log_{3}{10}} = n^{2.095}$. Now, can anyone please explain me, which of the three cases apply? If you [plot these functions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%5E2log%5E5(n)+vs+n%5E(2.095)+for+0+%3C+n+%3C+10000) you can see that $n^2\log^5 n$ clearly dominates. So, the answer should be $\Theta(n^2\log^5n)$.

However, if you try plugging in values in this [calculator](https://www.nayuki.io/page/master-theorem-solver-javascript), you see that the answer is $\Theta(n^{\log_{3}{10}})$. Does anyone have a formal reason? I am still confused as to which of these conditions apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plotting isn't foolproof: for any $k,\varepsilon>0$, we have $\log^kn = o(n^\varepsilon)$ (here, I've cancelled the common term of $n^2$). However, you can need to take $n$ *really* big to see it when $\varepsilon$ is small (e.g., $0.095$) and $k$ isn't so small (e.g., $5$).  [Here's the plot for $0\leq n\leq 10^{131}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(log(n))%5E5+vs+n%5E(0.095)+for+0+%3C+n+%3C+10%5E131), again with the $n^2$ term cancelled, and it looks quite different from your plot up to $n=10^5\,$!

Indeed, this question may even have been designed to catch you out if you try to compare the asymptotic growth by plotting instead of by understanding.

Comment: So, can we say that $n^a$ always dominates $n^b(logn)^k$, for $a > b$ and $k > 0$.

Comment: Correct. More information in our [reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/824/9550).

Comment: I am worried about the practical implication of this. Most of the real-life cases are going to be  $n < 10^{130}$. Shouldn't there be some measure that accurately measures what part of your algorithm is going to dominate at a certain input size?. Theoretically, I am not denying what has been said above.

Comment: Yes, this is a limitation of asymptotic analysis. The fact that we completely discard all multiplicative constants is usually a bigger issue, though. There are cases, such as matrix multiplication, where the asymptotically best algorithms aren't actually used because they only win out when the input is very, very big.

Comment: We also have a question [related to the practical aspects of asymptotic analysis](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9957/9550).