# Who said first "In practice, log log N is at most (single digit number)?"

Tags: time-complexity, big-o-notation, history

In one of my undergrad theory or algorithms classes, I remember a professor sharing a quip that went something like

> In practice, $\log(\log(N))$ is at most 9.

...the idea being that even though the function $f(N) = \log(\log(N))$ technically grows without bound, it's tiny for any value of $N$ that's remotely plausible for nearly any real-world problem, so an $O(\log(\log(N))$ algorithm is effectively constant-time. For example, $\log_2(\log_2($number of particles in the universe$)) \approx 8$. (It's even smaller if you use base $e$ or base 10.)

Does anyone know who first (or most famously) said this?

Googling this with various parts in quotes turns up plenty of lecture notes and tutorials about big-O notation and how slowly $\log(N)$ and $\log(\log(N))$ grow, but so far the earliest example I've found is [this lecture by Richard Borcherds in 2021](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgsHfMIQGSs&t=1226s), which is several years later than my memory of hearing it (and doesn't cite anyone else as the source of the remark).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is some historical quote that was famously said by someone, or that needs to be attributed to someone who said it.  It is just a mathematical fact.  I imagine many people have made a similar observation.

Your question is a little like asking "Who said first that 2+2=4?"  You'd probably give me a funny look if I asked that question.

See also [Is there a meaningful difference between O(1) and O(log n)?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/57814/755), ["For small values of n, O(n) can be treated as if it's O(1)"](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/35385/755), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Inverse (for a similar property of Ackerman's function), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm#Analysis_of_algorithms (for a similar fact about the iterated logarithm).

Answer (score 0):

I said it, and many people said it. It’s obvious when n is the size of a problem: if you wanted to sort all bits on all of Google’s hard drives, that’s less than $2^{80}$ bits, log n < 80, log log n < 6.34.

It’s not quite correct when n is a number. For example in a search for Fermat primes, we look at numbers around $2^{70,000,000}$, log n ≈ 70,000,000, log log n < 26.2.

Adding integers less than n takes O(log n), but in practice the time is constant for $n < 2^{64}$.

Comment: "I said it, and many people said it"—can you give a specific example?

Comment: Two specific examples: OP and I.