# What is the importance of c in big O notation?

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

From the definition of Big O, it states that there should be a function $g(x)$ such that it is always greater than or equal to $f(x)$. Or $f(x) \le cg(n)$ for all values of $n > n_0$. What I'm not able to understand is what is its importance in Big oh notation. Every question explains what is big-Oh and what how it uses useful. But I'm not able to understand what is $c$ actually in big-oh. There might be answer which I'm not able to get it due to its technical jargon.

Can someone explain me this in simple terms?

Comment: What is meant by $f(x) \le c.n$, did you mean $f(x) \le c \cdot g(x)$?

Comment: See [our reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/846/98).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Justification for neglecting constants in Big O](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9957/justification-for-neglecting-constants-in-big-o)

Answer (score 4):

Let's suppose the constant $c$ wasn't there: let's say that $f(n)=O'(g(n))$ if $f(n)\leq g(n)$ for all large enoun $n$. So, for example, $n=O'(n^2)$ and $\log n = O'(n)$, as you'd expect. But let's look at some functions whose growth rates are closer. First, let $f(n)=n+1$ and $g(n)=n$: well, $f(n)\neq O'(g(n))$ because $n+1 \not\leq n$ for all $n$.  Similarly, $2n\neq O'(n)$. SO, we see that the  constant $c$ is absolutely essential to the definition of $O(-)$: it just doesn't do what we want it to do if we remove it.

$O(-)$ measures the growth rate of functions ignoring constant factors. It gives you notation to say things like "$f$ is linear" or "$f$ is quadratic".  When we say "$f$ is linear", we don't distinguish between, say, $f(n)=n$ or $f(n)=4n$ or $f(n)=2n+12$: we ignore the constants. The constant $c$ in the definition of $O(-)$ allows it to ignore multiplicative constants and additive terms.

Comment: "it just doesn't do what we want it to do if we remove it" -- citation needed. Maybe [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9957/justification-for-neglecting-constants-in-big-o) or [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3523/explaining-the-relevance-of-asymptotic-complexity-of-algorithms-to-practice-of-d)? ;)